# Why does this not give me the file line by line

Tags: python

My code:

```
for line in decrypt_file:
    substitutionDecrypt(line,decrypt_key)
```

I have tried `readlines()` and can't think why this doesn't work.

i opened the file like this

```
try:
    decrypt_file = open(user_input,'r')
except IOError:
    print("File does not exist")
```

Comment: what is  `substitutionDecrypt`?

Comment: it replaces each letter with a different letter from a key but it says this is returning an io wrapper

Comment: I still don't see how it is supposed to output anything, how is it supposed to give your the output line by line?

Comment: im just trying to send a file line by line as strings to the fuction

Comment: on a sidenote us `with open()` to open your files

Comment: i don't understand what you mean could you explain please?

Comment: If your code doesn't produce the file line by line, then _what **does** it do_? We can hardly help you if all you say is "It doesn't work".

Comment: We can't debug this if you don't show us the definition of the `substitutionDecrypt()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's encrypted to binary as one long line. That's how encryption works. All the new line characters are scrambled. A possible fix would be to know the block size of the encryption algorithm and then just read in that many bytes on each iteration of your loop.

Comment: im kinda new how would one fix that? i am trying to send it line by line as a string

Comment: Kindly expound on your answer. Otherwise, just leave this as a comment.

Comment: @Dan, it sounds like the OP is using a substitution cipher, not real crypto, in which case this isn't necessarily accurate (unless it does in fact have newline characters mapped somewhere... but the OP's description indicates that it only maps letters).